# How to set and get unique name/tag to dynamically added child android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I have dynamically added 53 images to `ImageView` of my layout. I want to set unique id to each image that I added and want to get that id on image click. I have added a tag to my imageview `imageView.setTag(WirelessPin.arr_WirelessItems[i]);`  but onClick `ProductURL = (String) imageView.getTag();` always return the tag of last image i.e image no 53. How can I resolve this issue?

Here is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < WirelessPin.arr_WirelessItems.length; i++) {
                        url = new URL(WirelessPin.arr_WirelessItems[i].replaceAll("\\s+","%20"));
                        //ProductURL = WirelessPin.arr_WirelessItems[i];

                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url
                                .openConnection().getInputStream());

                        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(con);
                        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150, 110));
                        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                        imageView = new ImageView(con);
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(140, 84));
                        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        imageView.setTag(WirelessPin.arr_WirelessItems[i]);

                        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                //imageView.se

                                ProductURL = (String) imageView.getTag();
                                CollectDenominationsForWirelessPin obj = new CollectDenominationsForWirelessPin();
                                obj.WirelessPinDenominations(con, ProductURL, UserId);

                            }
                        });
                        layout.addView(imageView);
                        WirelessPin.sliderProducts.addView(layout);
                    }
```

Comment: What 'WirelessPin.arr_WirelessItems[i]' contains?

Comment: it contains url of images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OnClick method, change your code to

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;
ProductURL = (String) iv.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initialize `ImageView` inside `for loop` like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < WirelessPin.arr_WirelessItems.length; i++) {
    // Other Stuff
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(con);// Declare and initialize here
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(140, 84));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    imageView.setTag(WirelessPin.arr_WirelessItems[i]);
    //// Code
```

Comment: He doing the same thing.